# How to use django wizard with forms as a class attribute?

Tags: python, django, wizard, django-formwizard

I'm having some trouble with Django Form Wizards.

The specific part of the [documentation is around the `as_view` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.WizardView.as_view), it says you can pass in the list of forms as a class attribute, like so:

```
class ContactWizard(WizardView):
    form_list = [ContactForm1, ContactForm2]
```

But it doesn't give an example of how to call that in `urls.py`, so every iteration I've tried keeps giving this error:

```
AssertionError at /create/thing
at least one form is needed
```

I've tried these:

```
url(r'^create/thing$', views.ThingWizard.as_view),
     # TypeError
       object of type 'WSGIRequest' has no len()

url(r'^create/thing$', views.ThingWizard.as_view()),
     # AssertionError
       at least one form is needed

url(r'^create/thing$', views.ThingWizard),
     # TypeError __init__() takes exactly 1 argument

url(r'^create/thing$', views.ThingWizard()),
     # AttributeError at /create/thing
       'ThingWizard' object has no attribute 'rindex'
```

**Any tips?**

Answer (score 0):

Nothing to see here folks, it was a simple typo.

For future reference, its **`form_list`** **NOT** `forms_list`.